# How to get the id of my Sharepoint list template?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have found a list on the internet how to get the id of f.e. a list, a library, calendar, Tasks etc...
I have made a Sharepoint list and saved it as an template. Does my template has an id also? And how can i find that id?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf

Gr. P

Comment: How you saved the list as a template? I think custom list templates does not have the ID like the ones mentioned in documentation link you shared.

Comment: Oke thanks for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom template does not have an ID. However, it has a **BaseTemplate**. This base template ID refers to the [OOB template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf) you used to create your custom template.

For example, if you create a classic custom list and save it as template, it's `BaseTemplate` will be **100**.

If you create a document library and save it as a template, all libraries that use your template will have the **101** `BaseTemplate`.

Comment: Oke but how can i get my list template in the JSON-code:{
  "AllowContentTypes": true,
  "BaseTemplate": 100,
 "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
 "Description": "My list description",
 "Title":"@{variables('ListName')}"
}

Comment: You can call this URL: <YOUR_SITE>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YOUR_LIST_TITLE'). This will return a JSON you are looking for.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov I have a document library with BaseTemplate 10020. And I am unable to find the reason. Also causing issues with Sync, Explorer view, ModernUI etc. Would you be able to point out any reasons.  [Link][1]


  [1]: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303126/change-sp-list-basetemplate-property-list-definition-type-of-document-library/303153#303153