# Change SP.List.baseTemplate Property (list definition type) of document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2019, template

We have a SharePoint subsite which was created using No-Code Sandbox Solution. (*Actually the site was created in SharePoint 2013, recently we migrated it into SharePoint 2019*)

But the problem is, few document libraries in the site are having the type as 'List'. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Due to this (*we suspect*), the Document Library sync is not working. Even the 'modern ui' is not enabled.

[image]

**My question:-** Is there any way by which we can change the 'Type' ie **SP.List.baseTemplate Property (list definition type)** of the doc lib? Any suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Generally speaking, no...they're structured differently, so you can't just flip the template to something else.  A document library is centered around a document and accompanied by metadata.  A list is rows in a database that can have attachments.  I'm going to assume that the document that was represented in the doclib is now an attachment to the items in the list?  If so, you could script a lightweight conversion between the list and a new doclib...can't be done in-place.  Curious, what did you use for the migration because it clearly ignored the fact that it was a doclib?

Comment: @RobD'Oria The migration was from SP 2013 to 2019. It was a content database migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** baseTemplate is a **Read Only** property. Can't update the value.

**More Details:** I used the below Endpoint URI to find the **baseTemplate** property of the specific doc lib. [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246143(v=office.15))

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/baseTemplate
```

Found that the **baseTemplate** value assigned is wrong. (*for document library, it should be **101*** [Reference](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-list-templates/))

[image]

Tried updating the **baseTemplate** value using JSOM. But, later found that baseTemplate is a **Read Only** property.

Comment: 10020 is not an OOB basetemplate id.  So you likely migrated from 2013 without a feature being installed/activated/available in 2019.  If your 2013 instance is still available I would check to see what feature 10020 belongs.

Comment: I recommend creating a new Document library from scratch. There old library is either corrupt or was created incorrectly.